# Finite Field Book Recommendation

Tags: soft-question, finite-fields, book-recommendation

I know the basics of abstract algebra and would like to study finite fields. One book I found is Lectures on Finite Fields by [Xiang-Dong Hou](http://math.usf.edu/faculty/xdohou/). Hou is for sure an expert in Finite Fields but I am not sure if his book is best for beginners.

Any recommendation on books on Finite Fields for beginners?

Comment: Introduction to Finite Fields and their Applications 2nd Edition
by Rudolf Lidl  (Author), Harald Niederreiter (Author)

Comment: X.-D. Hou's book is nice (I have never met him in person, but once an accidental collision of independent results lead to me coauthoring an article with him). In the preface it does state that the material was selected with graduate courses in mind. The same applies to [*The Tome*](https://books.google.fi/books/about/Finite_Fields.html?id=xqMqxQTFUkMC&redir_esc=y). Most of the stuff I have learned about finite fields I picked from a study of that book. I did have an extensive algebra background when diving into it.

Comment: The recommendation depends on what you mean by *basics of abstract algebra*. If that means something like *Basic Algebra I* by Jacobson, then you will be fine with any choice. If it means that you have a course of algebraic structures (first course on groups, rings and fields), then you may want to start a level lower (but can move on to the good stuff soon).

Comment: Applications reach number theory, group theory, cryptography, algebraic geometry and many other fields. Assuming you have done a solid set of algebra undergraduate modules, I would google around and figure out what interests you and focus on that rather than going through a huge broad textbook.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I do not have nearly as much knowledge as in Jacobson's sense of basic algebra. I more or less know and only know what is typically covered in the first course of abstract algebra.

Comment: @sandy, I do not have any particular interest in the applications of finite fields; instead I would like to have a solid foundation in the subject itself.